# Fails to allocate derivative class to base class pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, polymorphism

I have a `AbstractFactory`, `WinFactory` and `IOSFactory` classes.

AbstactFactory inheritences WinFactory and IOSFactory as the following:

```
class IOSFacetory {
private:
    IOSRectButton *_rectbtn;
    IOSCircularButton *_circbtn;
public:
    IOSFacetory() : _rectbtn(NULL), _circbtn(NULL) {} // set rectbtn to null
    IOSRectButton* getIOSRectBtn () { 
        if(!_rectbtn) _rectbtn = new IOSRectButton;
        return _rectbtn;
    }

    IOSCircularButton* getIOSCircBtn() {
        if(!_circbtn) _circbtn = new IOSCircularButton;
        return _circbtn;
    }

    ~IOSFacetory() {
        if(_rectbtn) delete _rectbtn;
        if(_circbtn) delete _circbtn;
    }
};

class WinFacetory {
private:
    WinRectButton *_rectbtn;
    WinCircularButton *_circbtn;
public:
    WinFacetory() : _rectbtn(NULL), _circbtn(NULL) {} // set rectbtn to null
    WinRectButton* getWinRectBtn () { 
        if(!_rectbtn) _rectbtn = new WinRectButton;
        return _rectbtn;
    }

    WinCircularButton* getWinCircBtn() {
        if(!_circbtn) _circbtn = new WinCircularButton;
        return _circbtn;
    }

    ~WinFacetory() {
        if(_rectbtn) delete _rectbtn;
        if(_circbtn) delete _circbtn;
    }
};

class AbstractFactory : public WinFacetory, public IOSFacetory {
public:
    AbstractFactory(){}
};
```

in the `main` function, I'm trying to set a `IOSFactory` into a `AbstractFactory` Pointer:

```
#include "AbstractFactory.h"

int main() {
#ifdef _WIN
    AbstractFactory* factory = new WinFacetory;
#else 
    AbstractFactory* factory = new IOSFacetory;
#endif
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work and I get the following compilation error:

`IntelliSense: a value of type "IOSFacetory *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "AbstractFactory *`.

I guess I have a minor error but I can't figure it out. I'd like to get helped. thanks!

Comment: `AbstractFacetory` is an `IOSFacetory`. The converse is not true. You are trying to assign a base class pointer to a derived class one.

Comment: Note: you are leaking, you are leaking, you are leaking... try and investigate `std::unique_ptr` it should be supported by VC++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reverse your inheritance relations. AbstractFactory should be a base class of both IOSFactory and WinFactory.

Remember to declare a virtual destructor in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You should derive `WinFacetory` and `IOSFacetory` from `AbstractFactory`. Now you do it contrariwise.